# Is this series convergent or divergent? (with factorials/alternating series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n+2)!}}}$$

This wouldn't be a alternating series since there is no $(-1)^n$. And I don't think taking a risk of using The Ratio Test would be worth the gamble. I tried taking the limit, in order to use the limit comparison test, but I no longer think it is possible since there are factorials.

Comment: First rewrite the terms as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+2)(n+1)}}$, and then use the Comparison Test.

Comment: Really? Alright, is that usually helpful with factorial series in general or just this one in particular?

Comment: Ok, so if I was to re-write it for the comparison test then that would be smaller than my original series, so I would be hoping for that to diverge?

Comment: Don't use the Ratio Test, it will be inconclusive. The thing behaves more or less like $\frac{1}{n}$ (limit comparison) or alternately the $n$-th term is bigger than $\frac{1}{n+2}$, so we have divergence.

Comment: Yes I got it equal to 1 with the ratio test, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that the summand is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n + 1)(n + 2)}}.$$

> Then, notice that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n + 1)(n + 2)}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n + 2)(n + 2)}} = \frac{1}{n + 2}.$$

Comment: And we know that it is also less than the original sequence, meaning the whole thing will converge, towards 0 as n goes to infinity right?

Comment: Well, the *sequence* of terms converges to $0$. But the original *series* is $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n + 1) (n + 2)}}$, which is bounded below by the (divergent) series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n + 2}$, and so the original *series* diverges.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}} \geq \dfrac{1}{n+2}$

Comment: How do you reach this generalization ? How is this process called ?

Comment: @user2485710 $$\frac1{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{(n+2)(n+2)}}=\frac1{n+2}$$ The $\ge$ is justified because we are increasing the denominator, which can only make it smaller

Comment: @Quincunx I was assuming some kind of technique for doing approximations; I'm noticing that it's nothing like it. Thanks anyway .